# Getting error from play store - “This app is incompatible with all of your devices.”

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk

I've built my app, tested in emulator also. My own device also. But, when I"m uploading that APK file to PlayStore I'm getting error -

"**This app is incompatible with all of your devices**."

I changed my `supports-screens` tag from:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

to

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" />
```

Still not working.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="0.0.2" package="com.ionicframework.esp132862" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
</manifest>
```

This is my first app, I've built it using `ionic`. I've no idea how to deal with Android. Any guess what could be the problem, why is it saying it's uncompatible with my devices?

Comment: What is the Android version of your device(s)? Try to completely remove the `supports-screens` tag from you `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I've Nexus 5 & it has Android M inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I fixed the issue. The issue was from our side. Actually, I'm using Crosswalk with Ionic. So, I was getting 2 APK for upload to Play Store. And, here the catch is if you've multiple APK then in Google Play Console you need to switch to 'Advance Mode' from 'Standard Mode' which I didn't know about earlier. So, I was continuously trying to upload my 2 APK in standard mode & that's why something was breaking/missing in Google Play store side & I was getting that error.

But, now after uploading those APK by Advance mode that error has fixed.

Anyway, Thanks, all of your effort to help me out. I really Appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you explain me please how to do this?